# Alternatives to pickle's `persistent_id`?

Tags: python, json, persistence, yaml, pickle

I have been using Python's [pickle](http://docs.python.org/library/pickle.html)
module for implementing a thin file-based persistence layer.  The
persistence layer (part of a larger library) relies heavily on pickle's [persistent_id](http://docs.python.org/library/pickle.html#pickling-and-unpickling-external-objects) feature
to save objects of specified classes as separate files.

The only issue with this approach is that pickle files are not human
editable, and I'd much rather have objects saved in a format that is
human readable and editable with a text editor (e.g., YAML or JSON).

Do you know of any library that uses a human-editable format *and*
offers features similar to *pickle*'s `persistent_id`?  Alternatively,
do you have suggestions for implementing them on top of a YAML- or
JSON-based serialization library, without rewriting a large subset of
*pickle*?

Comment: It is difficult to make suggestions on how to implement a persistence system without any description of its purpose or requirements.

Comment: @taleinat well the question has a narrower scope than implementing a persistence system: is there any library that offers a feature similar to _pickle_'s `persistent_id` mechanism, but uses a human-editable format? (But you're right the last part could cause some confusion - I'll try to reword it)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I haven't tried this yet myself, but I think you should be able to do this elegantly with [PyYAML](http://pyyaml.org/wiki/PyYAML) using what they call ["representers" and "resolvers"](http://pyyaml.org/wiki/PyYAMLDocumentation#Constructorsrepresentersresolvers).

**EDIT**

After an extensive exchange of comments with the poster, here is a method to achieve the required behavior with PyYAML.

*Important Note:* If a `Persistable` instance has another such instance as an attribute, or contained somehow inside one of its attributes, then the contained `Persistable` instance will not be saved to yet another separate file, rather it will be saved inline in the same file as the parent `Persistable` instance. To the best of my understanding, this limitation also existed in the OP's pickle-based system, and may be acceptable for his/her use cases. I haven't found an elegant solution for this which doesn't involve hacking `yaml.representer.BaseRepresenter`.

```
import yaml
from functools import partial

class Persistable(object):
    # simulate a unique id
    _unique = 0

    def __init__(self, *args, **kw):
        Persistable._unique += 1
        self.persistent_id = ("%s.%d" %
                              (self.__class__.__name__, Persistable._unique))

def persistable_representer(dumper, data):
    id = data.persistent_id
    print "Writing to file: %s" % id
    outfile = open(id, 'w')
    outfile.write(yaml.dump(data))
    outfile.close()
    return dumper.represent_scalar(u'!xref', u'%s' % id)

class PersistingDumper(yaml.Dumper):
    pass

PersistingDumper.add_representer(Persistable, persistable_representer)
my_yaml_dump = partial(yaml.dump, Dumper=PersistingDumper)

def persistable_constructor(loader, node):
    xref = loader.construct_scalar(node)
    print "Reading from file: %s" % id
    infile = open(xref, 'r')
    value = yaml.load(infile.read())
    infile.close()
    return value

yaml.add_constructor(u'!xref', persistable_constructor)


# example use, also serves as a test
class Foo(Persistable):
    def __init__(self):
        self.one = 1
        Persistable.__init__(self)

class Bar(Persistable):
    def __init__(self, foo):
        self.foo = foo
        Persistable.__init__(self)

foo = Foo()
bar = Bar(foo)
print "=== foo ==="
dumped_foo = my_yaml_dump(foo)
print dumped_foo
print yaml.load(dumped_foo)
print yaml.load(dumped_foo).one

print "=== bar ==="
dumped_bar = my_yaml_dump(bar)
print dumped_bar
print yaml.load(dumped_bar)
print yaml.load(dumped_bar).foo
print yaml.load(dumped_bar).foo.one

baz = Bar(Persistable())
print "=== baz ==="
dumped_baz = my_yaml_dump(baz)
print dumped_baz
print yaml.load(dumped_baz)
```

From now on use `my_yaml_dump` instead of `yaml.dump` when you want to save instances of the `Persistable` class to separate files. But *don't* use it inside `persistable_representer` and `persistable_constructor`! No special loading function is necessary, just use `yaml.load`.

Phew, that took some work... I hope this helps!

Comment: Many thanks for the suggestion! However, I can't make this work (not easily, at least): https://gist.github.com/1348843 Main problems: (1) PyYAML decides which representer to use based on an object's primary class only, so adding an attribute `persistent_id` or making objects subclasses of a specified `Persistent` class does not work; (2) So the representer function cannot decide whether to use the "cross-ref" representation or the plain YAML one: this would require telling when the representer is called as part of dumping another object, or "natively"-otherwise we get infinite recursion.

Comment: Your code is entering an infinite recursion because you're calling `yaml.dump(data)` inside the representer, and you told `yaml.dump` to use that representer to dump that data! Try building upon the representer/constructor example in the PyYAML documentation page I linked to. Specifically, you should use `dumper.represent_scalar` instead of `yaml.dump` inside your representer, and `loader.construct_scalar` instead of `yaml.load` in your constructor.

Comment: Yes, I know why it's entering an infinite recursion.  The point is that I cannot use the `represent_scalar`/`construct_scalar` functions, because the "persistent" objects are not simple scalars, they are Python objects of which I have to get a "regular" YAML representation.  This is what pickle's `persistent_id` does: it generates the normal pickled representation, but saves it to a different file.

Comment: I see, you want to `yaml.dump` the object again but without the special treatment, and save that to a file, correct? If so, wouldn't doing the same thing with `pickle` would the same problem? How did you overcome this in your pickle-based solution?

Comment: Yes, correct.  In the pickle-based solution I did not do any special magic; it's a feature of pickle, documented [here](http://docs.python.org/library/pickle.html#pickling-and-unpickling-external-objects).

Comment: In the example on the site, a specific `pickle.Pickler` instance is created, and the `persistent_id` hook is set only on that instance. If inside `persistent_id` you used `pickle.dump` or `pickle.dumps`, they would use a different `Pickler` without the `persistent_id`, and therefore it would work. I'll update my answer with a method to do this with PyYAML.